# what is the word for someone not trying their best or performing badly on purpose?

Tags: verbs, slang

It sounds like a street slang, but both webster and urban dictionary gave the same definition.
Can't remember what the word/phrase for it is - like when someone plays bad at first to hustle someone else.

Comment: An idiom used to describe a deliberate failure or bad performance is **take the fall**.  This doesn't really fit for the idea of trying to dupe your opponent by making them think you suck only to hustle them later, though.  **Play the fool** better fits with the idea of deliberate deception, but doesn't necessarily imply the hustling idea, either.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, these expressions are used in pool when played in Florida:

**stall**:

> As in "Joe get off the stall, I know you're a better player   than
>   this."   The person is playing below his ability in order to obtain
>   a more favorable match at a later time.  Hiding your true skill.

and

(to) **lemonade**:

> To intentionally play below ones speed.  Also, *to go on the lemon*.

[Source](http://www.sfbilliards.com/Misc/jargon.html)

Elsewhere...

**On the lemon**

> Being *[on the lemon](http://www.billiardsforum.info/billiard-terms-definition/on-the-lemon.asp)* is a perceived state by others that one is
>   playing, intentionally, below their real level of skill with the
>   intent of deception for financial gain. When a player is on the lemon,
>   they are said to be sandbagging.
>
> Normally in later games, they will begin to play at their real skill
>   level, win the game, and thus, take the money.

**Sandbagging**

> Sandbagging occurs, in a one pocket context, when a player stalls
>   early in a handicapped event to obtain a lower rating, so that late in
>   the event they can win more easily by benefiting from the erroneous
>   handicap. In more general cue sport terms, a player is said to be
>   sandbagging when they intentionally disguise their true playing
>   ability in early games with the intent of soliciting bets and
>   opponents.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, according to "The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English" *by Tom Dalzell (Senior Editor) and Terry Victor (Editor)*;

**"stroke it"** fits to your definition:

[image]

I'm not sure how common this phrase is though and it has other connotations as well.

[Mari-Lou A](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44619/mari-lou-a)'s answers include terms that have more common usage obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia, a "dead'un" is a horse that is deliberately run to lose.

Comment: *Please* provide at least a reference, anything to backup your answer. Good answers are not only informative but also self-contained.